# Верстка Креативного NFT Лендинга HTML, Sass | Scss, JS, Gulp. Работа с svg

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, gulp

Изучаю [Фронтенд простыми словами](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLu0pRheOFLkEmnlzsKsEjapldwlXd18Ba), а именно [2-й урок](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RfNUJXY3uGg&list=PLu0pRheOFLkEmnlzsKsEjapldwlXd18Ba&index=3&t=29s). Скачал с

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

готовую верстку второго урока, а именно с https://github.com/web-dev404/NFT-Landing архив с папкой NFT-Landing-main.zip. Разархивировал архив в папку D:\OSPanel\domains\NFT-Landing-main и переименовал её в папку nftland

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Открыл ее в VSCode

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и заметил, что в папке dist (созданной с помощью gulp) нет файла `img/icons/icons.svg#arrow-down`. В src есть файлы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

`arrow-down.svg` и другие, но они не преобразовались в папку `dist/img/icons`.

Пытался запустить

```
npm run svgSprive
```

но в папке `dist` не была создана папка `img/icons` с нужными файлами. Как создать svg файлы в нужной папке (в папке `dist`)? Из за того, что файлы не преобразовались по нужному пути в папке dist, svg картинки на сайте не отображаются.

Привожу код файла svgSprive.js

```
import svgSprite from "gulp-svg-sprite";

export const svgSprive = () => {
    return app.gulp.src(`${app.path.src.svgicons}`, {})
    .pipe(app.plugins.plumber(
        app.plugins.notify.onError({
            title: "SVG",
            message: "Error: <%= error.message %>"
        })
    ))
    .pipe(svgSprite({
        mode: {
            stack: {
                sprite: `../icons/icons.svg`,
                example: true
            }
        }
    }))
    .pipe(app.gulp.dest(`${app.path.build.images}`));
}
```

Аккуратно следовал инструкциям в статье по созданию слайдера.
Но, в папке **dist** не была создана папка **img/icons** с нужными файлами.

***Как создать svg файлы в нужной папке (в папке dist)?***

Comment: Поставил (+) за хорошо оформленный вопрос. Сейчас это большая редкость. Уверен, что ваш вопрос и ответ будут полезны. Ещё наверное нужно как-то изменить заголовок, чтобы поисковики находили ваш вопрос и ответ при более общих запросах. Сейчас я временно отредактирую заголовок, чтобы снять вопрос от закрытия Уже 3 голоса. При 5 вопрос закроется автоматически.

Comment: вы автор вопроса, поэтому у вас наверное лучше получится изменить заголовок для большей актуальности

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я вызывал команды `npm run svgSprive`, `npm run dev` не в том порядке. Необходимо было вызывать сначала `npm run dev`, а затем `npm run svgSprive`, потому что в противном случае `npm run dev` перезаписывало бы папку `dist\img\icons`, созданную `npm run svgSprive`.

Comment: сниппет нашего сайта запрещает подключение сторонних файлов. Поэтому, если у вас уже, что-то готово, разместите пожалуйста заготовку вашего проекта в какую-нибудь песочнице:

  [CodePen](https://codepen.io/)  [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/) [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/)

  [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) 

JSFiddle самая популярная песочница, но в данный момент закрыта для разработчиков из России